# How to run background process in watchOS?

Tags: swift, watchos, watchos-3

I have made my first app for apple watch and faced with impossible to send data every 10 seconds to my backend .

Application is frozen when display turns off and running again from scratch when display is on.

I tryed to run workout session like in [this example](https://github.com/mathiasnagler/watchOS-Background-Haptics/blob/master/watchOS-Background-Haptics%20WatchKit%20Extension/InterfaceController.swift).

But it doesn't help, app is frozen after 10 seconds of inactivity.

I try to send accelerometer data to my backend every 10 seconds in InterfaceController.swift:

```
//...
override func willActivate() {
    super.willActivate()
    startWorkout() //it's copied from example
    startAnglesTracker()
}

func startAnglesTracker() {
    if motion.isAccelerometerAvailable && !motion.isAccelerometerActive {
        motion.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 10
        motion.startAccelerometerUpdates(to: OperationQueue.main) {
            //sending here
        }
    }
}

private func startWorkout() {
    let workoutConfiguration = HKWorkoutConfiguration()
    workoutConfiguration.activityType = .crossTraining
    workoutConfiguration.locationType = .indoor
    do {
        workoutSession = try HKWorkoutSession(configuration: workoutConfiguration)
        workoutSession?.delegate = self
        healthStore.start(workoutSession!)
        vibrate()
    } catch {
        serverData.setText("workoutSession error")
    }
}
//...

extension InterfaceController: HKWorkoutSessionDelegate {
    func workoutSession(_ workoutSession: HKWorkoutSession, didFailWithError error: Error) {

    }

    func workoutSession(_ workoutSession: HKWorkoutSession, didGenerate event: HKWorkoutEvent) {

    }

    func workoutSession(_ workoutSession: HKWorkoutSession, didChangeTo toState: HKWorkoutSessionState, from fromState: HKWorkoutSessionState, date: Date) {

    }
}
```

It works only when display is active.

Comment: Not enough information. Show us your code. What are you trying to do and when does it freeze? What debugging have you done in order to narrow down the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I have added info with code.

Comment: There's no workout related code in your question. Gathering accelerometer data is not a valid background mode in watchOS. You need to be running an `HKWorkoutSession` if you want to use your app as a workout app.

Comment: Added code related with workout